# Dayforce Reporting Custom Field SQL: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been researching this issue for quite some time and I have been unable to find a solution. I am hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction.  I continue to get the following error:

> "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the
> group by list of a GROUP BY clause."

I am writing this as a custom field within Dayforce Reporting, which does have some oddities compared to sql server so I'm hoping that it is something small I am overlooking.  Any advice is greatly appreciated as all my research has come up empty. I have tried adding an aggregate function such as TOP 1 or MAX and also tried adding GROUP BY clauses to no avail. The script is below.  Thank you!

```
(SELECT x.TaxAuthorityCode
 FROM (SELECT tai.PRTaxAuthorityInstanceId, ta.PRTaxAuthorityCode TaxAuthorityCode
       FROM PRTaxAuthorityInstance tai
       JOIN PRPayrollTax pt ON pt.PRTaxAuthorityInstanceId = tai.PRTaxAuthorityInstanceId
       JOIN PRTaxAuthority ta ON ta.PRTaxAuthorityId = tai.PRTaxAuthorityId) x
 WHERE x.PRTaxAuthorityInstanceId = PRPayrollTax.PRTaxAuthorityInstanceId);
```

Comment: This looks like part of a larger query, otherwise that `WHERE` doesn't make any sense. Please describe what you are trying to do, what your tables look like, and preferably some sample data. And of course your complete query.

Comment: Hi HoneyBadger. Thank you for the reply. Sadly Dayforce Reporting does not allow access to the full sql query.  For the custom field section this would be the entire query. However, I do have the PRPayrollTax table as part of the main report if that helps. All other tables mentioned above are not currently part of the report.  It's a very clunky tool in my experience. I wish I could write complete queries to access all the tables, but this system requires you to use their user friendly style of report building that joins tables for you and you can only use sql in their custom fields.